# Erasing Image using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, erase

Could someone give an suggestion about how to erase an image using another image?

Like erase concept in ArcMap.

Like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is `unmask`. Here's an example

```js
// Replace mask and value of the input image with the mask and value of another image
var outputImage = inputImage.updateMask(eraseImage.unmask().not()) ;
```

Here is a link to a sample code - https://code.earthengine.google.com/2fd60f7625b3446ad943b8bb7ff716e5

Answer (score 0):

you can use following concept in Google Earth Engine

Example Code -

```
// define images, 
var imageE = eraseFeatue 
var imageI = input 

// define the area to keep 
var wahatToKeep = imageE.not();

// then mask the input image from above outcome of what to keep
var output = input.mask(whatToKeep);
```

please note that this is an example code only.